# Having problems understand the MySQL IF() and ELSE()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely fine with PHP IF() and ELSEIF(). However today I started to work with MySQL commands, I have a long MySQL query and I can't understand how I modify it.

Here is the code:

```
$db->colums[] = "
IF(
    (SELECT
        IF(p.delivery = '1',IF(distance < deliverymilesto1, deliverysurcharge1,
            IF (distance < deliverymilesto2, deliverysurcharge2,
                IF (distance < deliverymilesto3, deliverysurcharge3,
                    IF (distance < deliverymilesto4, deliverysurcharge4, 
                        IF(distance < deliverymilesto5,deliverysurcharge5,0)
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 0)
        FROM products prod WHERE prod.id_product = p.id_product
    ) > 0,
    (p.price +  (SELECT
        IF(p.delivery = '1',IF(distance < deliverymilesto1, deliverysurcharge1,
            IF (distance < deliverymilesto2, deliverysurcharge2,
                IF (distance < deliverymilesto3, deliverysurcharge3,
                    IF (distance < deliverymilesto4, deliverysurcharge4, 
                        IF(distance < deliverymilesto5,deliverysurcharge5,0)
                         )
                     )
                 )
             ), 0)
             FROM products prod WHERE prod.id_product = p.id_product
        )),
    (p.price)
)as pricedelivery";
```

What I need to do is create an ELSE statement if p.delivery equals '2', and add in the following code:

```
IF(p.delivery = '2', IF(find_in_set('".$outcoder."', deliveryoutcode1), deliveryoutcharge1,
IF(find_in_set('".$outcoder."', deliveryoutcode2), deliveryoutcharge1, deliveryoutcharge2, 0)), 0)
```

in PHP this is simple as it would be:

```
if($delivery = '1') {
...code here
} elseif($delivery = '2') {
...otherwise
}
```

But I just can't understand the logic of how to change my statment. Maybe my brain is tired because I'be been learning about normalisation today. Can anyone help me here, thanks.

**EDIT: I have spent the entire morning cleaning up the MySQL, result of which is above, based on what I have so far learnt about MySQL.**

However, I would now like to be able to rewrite this using `case`, based on the useful comments I've received. I have 5 such MySQL queries on my page and I wonder if someone can be kind enough to rewrite the above in `case`format, then I can use this to rewrite the other queries? Thank you.

Comment: First thing to realize: sql is not a programming language. So the best would be to not even try to apply imperative programming idioms to it.

Comment: Convert the statement to `case` . . . it'll make much more sense.

Comment: well I am going to have to normalise my database if I want this to work. It's silly of me storing stuff as an array in a table cell. I'm off to oDesk to hire someone as this job is too tough for me, I know my limits. But thanks everyone for caring / Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  price +
  case delivery
      when '1' then
          case
              when distance < deliverymilesto1 then deliverysurcharge1
              when distance < deliverymilesto2 then deliverysurcharge2
              when distance < deliverymilesto3 then deliverysurcharge3
              when distance < deliverymilesto4 then deliverysurcharge4
              when distance < deliverymilesto5 then deliverysurcharge5
              else 0   
          end
      when '2' then
          case
              when distance < deliverymilesto1 then deliveryoutcharge1
              when distance < deliverymilesto2 then deliveryoutcharge2
              when distance < deliverymilesto3 then deliveryoutcharge3
              when distance < deliverymilesto4 then deliveryoutcharge4
              when distance < deliverymilesto5 then deliveryoutcharge5
              else 0   
          end
      else 0
  end
FROM products
```

`IF()` as a function is not the same as the branching you're used to. The first argument is a condition, the second argument is what is returned when the condition evaluates to true, the third is the opposite case when it's false.

Your code above just uses a lot of nesting in the third argument (the else branch) to accomplish what you'd normally do with IF...ELSE... or equivalently with the `CASE` expression.

You'll have to incorporate that into the rest of your query since you've left some of it out.

Comment: still trying to integrate this into my code, I'll keep on trying but thanks so far for the input. I'll update you tomorrow on my progress.

Comment: ok so my question is updated @shawnt00 but no luck with the code, can you see what I've maybe done wrong? I'm testing the case statement on the original code first. Thx.

Comment: You shouldn't need any of the `IF()` at all anymore. But I'm not sure what the whole `colums` thing is about. Is it a list of columns built up as part of a larger query?

Comment: well i was up until 2 last night and no luck. I think my frustration is getting the better of my brain. Now this morning 4 hours just starting at the code. I think the problem is all the nestling and the fact I am a complete beginner at MySQL.

Comment: I've marked this an the answer because it is the solution to a way or rewriting my code. But my issues a deeper than this and I need to rewrite my entire database now. Thanks for your help.